# How to validate custom text field in magento checkout form

Tags: validation, custom-field

I have added custom checkout field in magento 2, and made it required, how can I add more validations and custom messages.
Below is my code snippet to make it required:

```
dataScope' => 'shippingAddress' . '.' . $customAttributeCode,
            'description' => 'Save This Address',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => 40,
            'id'  => 'shipping_dob',
            'value' => '',
            'label' => 'Shipping Birth Date',
            'placeholder' => 'MM/DD/YYYY',
            'validation' => [
               'required-entry' => true
            ]
```